# try to run 'exiftool' from applescript but get 'command not found'

Tags: terminal, applescript

this is my first attempt to run a shell script, namely 'exiftool', from applescript:

```
    set cmd to "exiftool -" & tag & "='" & myName & "' " & myFile
    do shell script cmd
```

cmd looks like this:*exiftool -Artist='myName' myFile.jpg*
and works perfectly when directly inserted in Terminal.
*exiftool* was installed by the standard installer!

What did i miss?

Answer (score 1):

Run

```
which exiftool
```

or

```
type exiftool
```

and use that path instead of `exiftool` in the script.

For e.g. if I was using [`git`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) in Automator, I'd do this.

```
/usr/bin/git pull
```

Modify this for `exiftool` usage.

Comment: Great! '/usr/local/bin/exiftool' did the job.Could you shortly explain why the location is different?

Comment: This is due to the fact that `Applescript` use the standard Mac PATH to find applications. On the other hand, `Terminal` is using the PATH you can modify through `~/.profile` (for example with a `bash` shell).

Comment: @dan that edit was not correct. I showed an usage of `git` command since I don't know about exiftool. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull

Comment: @pawi the duplicate answer & dan's comment explain that.